# How to manage Login Session variables in MVC

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, session-variables

I have search the web including SO but couldn't find the best solution to the problem. I have taken over a MVC project which has around 15 controllers and each controller class starts with these 2 lines:

`int userid = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"];
 string usertype = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserType"];`

[Code Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDGuY.jpg)

These 2 variables (userid,usertype) are then used throught the controller action methods.

What would be the best way of avoiding this? The 2 options that I found were either creating a SessionEndAttribute class and add it to each controller OR create a base controller class with the session check and make all controller classes inherit from the BaseController class.

This is what I have done for the moment, let me know if this is the right way

Controller :

```
[SessionExpire]
public class WordShareController : Controller
{

    int userid = 0;
    string usertype = string.Empty;

    public WordShareController() : this(new SessionManagement())
    {

    }
    public WordShareController(SessionManagement objSession)
    {
        userid = objSession.UserId;
        usertype = objSession.UserType;

    }
```

SessionManagement.cs

```
public class SessionManagement
{
    private int _userId = 0;
    private String _userType, _userName, _webName = string.Empty;

    public SessionManagement()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            _userId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]);
            _userType = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserType"]);
            _userName = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"]);
            _webName = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["WebName"]);
        }
    }

    public int UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return _userId;
        }
    }
    public string UserType
    {
        get
        {
            return _userType;
        }
    }
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return _userName;
        }
    }
    public string WebName
    {
        get
        {
            return _webName;
        }
    }

}
```

SessionExpireAttribute.cs

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
        // If the browser session or authentication session has expired...
        if (session.IsNewSession || session["LoginUser"] == null)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                // For AJAX requests, return result as a simple string, 
                // and inform calling JavaScript code that a user should be redirected.
                JsonResult result = new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = "SessionTimeout",
                    ContentType = "text/html"
                };
                filterContext.Result = result;
            }
            else
            {
                // For round-trip requests,
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary {
            { "Controller", "User" },
            { "Action", "Login" }
                });
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the right way to go ? Anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is you can create a separate class and implement the mvc AuthorizeAttribute class. Then you can register this class in App_Start -> FiletrConfig.cs

The code would look like this:

```
public class Authenticate : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpcontext)
    {
        //your authentication code from session or query string
    }
}
```

In FilterConfig.cs you register this Authenticate class like this

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new Authenticate());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but wouldn't this filter fire for each request? for e.g. pages like about,contact,home which don't need authentication?

Comment: For that you can add [AllowAnonymous] attribute on the actions of the controller where authorization is not required.